# Using namespace and using directive not working for std::enable_if_t

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

When I tried to compile the following code using MSCL 19, it's OK. However, when I tried g++ 6.2.0 and clang 3.9.0, I got an error like `expected nested-name-specifier class=typename`

```
#include<type_traits>
using namespace std;
template<class T,class=typename enable_if_t<
    is_signed<T>::value&&is_integral<T>::value&&(sizeof(T)>1)>>
    void f(T i) {}
int main() {
    f(1);
}
```

Adding `using std::enable_if_t` will produce the same result.

```
#include<type_traits>
using namespace std;
using std::enable_if_t;
template<class T,class=typename enable_if_t<
    is_signed<T>::value&&is_integral<T>::value&&(sizeof(T)>1)>>
void f(T i) {
}
int main(){
    f(1);
}
```

This issue can be solved by prefixing the `enable_if_t` with `std::`:

```
#include<type_traits>
using namespace std;
template<class T,class=typename std::enable_if_t<
    is_signed<T>::value&&is_integral<T>::value&&(sizeof(T)>1)>>
void f(T i) {
}
int main(){
    f(1);
}
```

Why the `using namespace std` and `using std::enable_if_t` are invalid to `std::enable_if_t`?

Comment: `typename` is unnecessary here.

Comment: FWIW, you might be able to use `is_integral_v<T>` instead of `is_integral<T>::value`, since you already have `enable_if_t<T>`

Comment: @Eric : `enable_if_t` is C++14, but `is_integral_v` is C++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it tries to tell you is when it sees `typename` it expects a nested type specifier next. And `enable_if_t` is used without any nesting (no `::`). Removing `typename` makes it work with gcc.